# Abstract algebra. Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A little lost here,please help further...

If $M$ and $N$ are normal subgroups of $G$ and $N\leq M$.

prove that $(G/N)/(M/N)\cong G/M$

Beyond showing it to be well defined I'm a lost.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and invest a little more time writing nicely, with capital letters for groups and subgroups as usual in all the world and writing complete words (ISO?)...and be clear beyond any doubt.

Comment: Do you want to say $(G/N)/(M/N)\cong G/M$ for $N\leq M$?

Comment: Yes I do. Sorry I'm a little new to this. I'll be more aware in the future.

Comment: ISO was meant to be isomorphic. Auto correct.

Comment: To be clear, $N\le M$ is indicating that $N$ is a subgroup of $M$? For the question, you can't talk about "well-defined" yet because well-defined refers to functions. By definition, a group is isomorphic to another if there exists a function from one group to the other that is a bijective homomorphism. The straightforward method would be to come up with a function from one group to the other and then prove that the function satisfies what I said. You'll probably find the First Isomorphism Theorem to be helpful since you're working with factor groups (if I'm reading the notation correctly).

Comment: Can you think of an obvious homomorphism from $G/N\longrightarrow G/M$ which is surjective and whose kernel is $M/N$.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the elements that make up $G/N$. It is is the set of cosets of $N$ in $G$. That is,
$G/N=\{ Ng \mid g \in G\}$
Is $M/N$ a normal subgroup of this quotient group? It would take a couple of lines to prove it, but you should. Assume that you have proved that $M/N$ is normal in $G/N$.
Now what does $(G/N)/(M/N)$ look like?
$(G/N)/(M/N)=\{(M/N)g \mid g \in (G/N)\}$

Elements of $(G/N)$ are of the form $Ng$, elements of $(M/N)$ are of the form $Nm$ for $m \in M$. In multiplying them, we are multiplying $(Nm)(Ng),n \in N, g \in G$. Having identified the elements of $(G/N)/(M/N)$, it is easy to see what the required homomorphism should be. 
Define $\phi:(G/N)/(M/N) \rightarrow G/M$ as

$
 NmNg \phi=
\begin{cases}
     M & \text{if }  g \in M \\
     Mg & \text{if } g \in G \setminus M.
\end{cases}
$

The kernel of $\phi$ would be the set of cosets of $N$ in $M$.